# cygwin install hangs on /etc/postinstall/0p_update-info-dir.dash

Tags: installation, cygwin

I just downloaded https://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe
and used a few mirrors like cygwin.mirror.constant.com
w/o success

I read that file `/etc/postinstall/0p_update-info-dir.dash`
it hangs when running md5sum: `ls -n /usr/share/info/*info* | md5sum >/usr/share/info/.stamp.tmp`
because neither the file `.stamp.tmp` nor `.stamp.tmp` are being created

at the log here there is this:

```
Cygwin WARNING:
  Couldn't compute FAST_CWD pointer.  This typically occurs if you're using
  an older Cygwin version on a newer Windows.  Please update to the latest
  available Cygwin version from https://cygwin.com/.  If the problem persists,
  please see https://cygwin.com/problems.html
```

but if I try to run md5sum directly it shows the same above warning.

it happens on windowsxp and windows 7

I tried a huge lot of tips and tricks from removing log files to deleting the whole install path to start again but it did not help

If you are being able to install cygwin on 2022, tell me how you did it?

PS.: that warning comes from bin/cygwin1.dll

Comment: Windows XP is not anymore supported by the current Cygwin. See https://superuser.com/questions/1132000/is-it-still-possible-to-get-cygwin-for-xp    Windows 7 should work

Comment: It did not work on w7, I wonder if someone has actually tested it? could be other w version too, I just need to know a w version that is working. I need to prepare a bash script (because I dont know windows .bat coding with loops and variables etc) for windows users and the only way I know is using cygwin.